# Spring Stomp slow connection

Tags: spring, websocket, stomp

I'm experiencing a slow Stomp connection between two Spring microservices, the client takes about 5 minutes to send the CONNECT Stomp message. Both microservices run on the same node.

Spring Boot version: 2.1.3.RELEASE

The Websocket server is configured in the following way:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws-subscribe").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
    }
}
```

The client is configured this way:

```
@Component
public class WebsocketClient {

    private GlobalConfiguration globalConfiguration;
    private WebsocketListener websocketListener;

    private WebSocketStompClient stompClient;

    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenGenerator jwtTokenGenerator;

    private ApplicationContext appContext;

    private Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebsocketClient.class);

    @Autowired
    public WebsocketClient(ApplicationContext context,GlobalConfiguration globalConfiguration) {
        Transport webSocketTransport = new WebSocketTransport(new StandardWebSocketClient());
        List<Transport> transports = Collections.singletonList(webSocketTransport);

        SockJsClient sockJsClient = new SockJsClient(transports);
        sockJsClient.setMessageCodec(new Jackson2SockJsMessageCodec());

        this.stompClient = new WebSocketStompClient(sockJsClient);

        this.globalConfiguration = globalConfiguration;
        this.websocketListener = new WebsocketListener(context);
    }

    public ListenableFuture<StompSession> connectToWebsocket(){
       String url = globalConfiguration.getOrchestratorWs();

        StompHeaders connectHeaders = new StompHeaders();

        WebSocketHttpHeaders webSocketHttpHeaders = new WebSocketHttpHeaders();
        webSocketHttpHeaders.add("Authorization",jwtTokenGenerator.token);

        LOGGER.info("webSocketHttpHeaders: " + webSocketHttpHeaders.toString());
        LOGGER.info("url: " + url);

        this.stompClient.setMessageConverter(new MappingJackson2MessageConverter());
        return stompClient.connect(url,webSocketHttpHeaders,connectHeaders, websocketListener);
    }
}
```

And client-side we have this Websocket listener:

```
public class WebsocketListener extends StompSessionHandlerAdapter {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebsocketListener.class);


    private GlobalConfiguration globalConfiguration;
    private ApplicationContext appContext;


    public WebsocketListener(ApplicationContext appContext) {
        this.appContext = appContext;
        this.globalConfiguration = appContext.getBean(GlobalConfiguration.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterConnected(StompSession session, StompHeaders connectedHeaders) {
        LOGGER.info("New session established : " + globalConfiguration.getId());
        session.subscribe("/topic/injections/"+globalConfiguration.getId(), this);
        LOGGER.info("Subscribed to /topic/injections/"+globalConfiguration.getId());
      //  session.send("/app/chat", getSampleMessage());
      //  logger.info("Message sent to websocket server");
    }

    @Override
    public void handleException(StompSession session, StompCommand command, StompHeaders headers, byte[] payload, Throwable exception) {
        LOGGER.error("Got an exception", exception);
    }

    @Override
    public Type getPayloadType(StompHeaders headers) {
        return Map.class;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleFrame(StompHeaders headers, Object payload) {
        LOGGER.info("Injection Received : " + payload);
        InjectionHandler injectionHandler = new InjectionHandler(appContext,(HashMap) payload);
        injectionHandler.start();
    }
}
```

The afterConnected is invoked about 5 minutes after the ws://10.2.0.43:7071/ws-subscribe/513/8306a7ac357847678795b049450fb6c5/websocket

Inspecting the source code of the Stomp library, I saw that the code where the microservice remains stuck for those 5 minutes is the following:

```
public ListenableFuture<StompSession> connect(URI url, @Nullable WebSocketHttpHeaders handshakeHeaders, @Nullable StompHeaders connectHeaders, StompSessionHandler sessionHandler) {
    Assert.notNull(url, "'url' must not be null");
    ConnectionHandlingStompSession session = this.createSession(connectHeaders, sessionHandler);
    WebSocketStompClient.WebSocketTcpConnectionHandlerAdapter adapter = new WebSocketStompClient.WebSocketTcpConnectionHandlerAdapter(session);
    this.getWebSocketClient().doHandshake(adapter, handshakeHeaders, url).addCallback(adapter);
    return session.getSessionFuture();
}
```

In particular, the session.getSessionFuture() call.
Any idea on what may cause the delay in the CONNECT message sent by the client?

Comment: Hey, wondering if you ever found a solution? I am having the same slow connection issues with Stomp and Java Spring

Comment: @Shane unfortunately we have not understood the cause of that behavior. Right now after having deployed the microservice on a different virtualized node we have not experienced this anymore. It seems it may be related with the particular context in which the microservice is deployed.